# Is the dot product on $\mathbf{R}^n$ ($n\ge 2$) Lipschitz?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inner-products, lipschitz-functions

> Let $n\ge 2$ be some positive integer. Let $f:\mathbf{R}^n\times\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ be defined as $f(x,y)=x\cdot y$ where $x\cdot y$ denotes the dot product of two vectors. Is $f$ Lipschitz?

This question is a generalization of [the 1D case](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4321561/999772) I asked earlier. The dot product in the higher dimension case is now nontrivial, i.e., not the scalar multiplication.

After the 1D case was done, I tried to mimic the [analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4321574/) there to show that $f$ is not Lipschitz. But here is an unsuccessful attempt.

Consider the vectors $x,u,v\in\mathbf{R}^n$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
|f(x,u)-f(x,v)|=|x\cdot(u-v)|\le |x||u-v|_{\mathbf{R}^n}\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand,
$$
|(x,u)-(x,v)|_{\mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}^n} = |(0,u-v)|_{\mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}^n} = |u-v|_{\mathbf{R}^n}\tag{2}
$$

The trouble to use the 1D case analysis is that one does not have the "equality" in (1) and thus cannot directly use (1) and (2) to reach a contradiction assuming a Lipschitz constant $K$.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I "reduce" the dimensions more, I can recover the equal sign in (1), and thus the 1D argument works again.

Let $x,u,v$ be three *real numbers* and $e_1=(1,0,\cdots,0)$ the unit vector in $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Now consider
$$
|f(xe_1,ue_1)-f(xe_1,ve_1)|=|x||u-v|=|x|\cdot \|ue_1-ve_1\|_{\mathbf{R}^n}\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\|(xe_1,ue_1)-(xe_1,ve_1)\|_{\mathbf{R}^n\times \mathbf{R}^n}
=\|ue_1 -ve_1\|_{\mathbf{R}^n}\tag{2}
$$

Comparing (1) and (2), one can see that $f$ cannot be Lipschitz, since otherwise, there exists $K>0$ such that
$$
|x|\cdot \|ue_1-ve_1\|_{\mathbf{R}^n}
=|f(xe_1,ue_1)-f(xe_1,ve_1)|
\le K\|ue_1 -ve_1\|_{\mathbf{R}^n}\tag{3}
$$
for *all* $x,u,v\in\mathbb{R}$, which is impossible.

If one looks at (3) further, one can fix $u=1$ and $v=0$ in the whole argument to simplify the contradiction to the estimate
$$
|x|\le K,\quad x\in\mathbf{R}\;.
$$

Comment: This is correct and works in any non-empty, not equal to $\{0\}$, inner product space over $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb C$). Consider $V$ to be any vector space over (for instance) $\mathbb R$ that contains $\{0\}$ as a strict subset. Then fix any $v\in V$ with $v\neq0$. We obtain $$\langle x v, v\rangle -\langle x v,0\rangle = x \lVert v\rVert^2$$ for all $x\in[0,\infty[$. The right-hand side grows to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, but for global Lipschitzness it should be uniformly bounded by $K  \lVert v\rVert$ for some absolute real constant $K$.